# RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 78 but got size 102 for tensor number 1 in the list

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to try the example of this library [graph_weather](https://github.com/openclimatefix/graph_weather?tab=readme-ov-file)

```
import torch
from graph_weather import GraphWeatherForecaster
from graph_weather.models.losses import NormalizedMSELoss

lat_lons = []
for lat in range(-90, 90, 1):
    for lon in range(0, 360, 1):
        lat_lons.append((lat, lon))
model = GraphWeatherForecaster(lat_lons)

features = torch.randn((2, len(lat_lons), 78))

out = model(features)
criterion = NormalizedMSELoss(lat_lons=lat_lons, feature_variance=torch.randn((78,)))
loss = criterion(out, features)
loss.backward()
```

When I get to the line of code `out = model(features)` I got this error message:

```
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 78 but got size 102 for tensor number 1 in the list.
```

the

```
len(lat_lons)
64800
features.shape
torch.Size([2, 64800, 78])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the second issue in the [repo](https://github.com/openclimatefix/graph_weather/issues/82) (4 days back), you can simply change the feature shape vector from `78` to `102` dimensions:

```py
features = torch.randn((2, len(lat_lons), 102))
```